# How do I properly tell someone to proceed with a transaction in an email?

Tags: translation, business-japanese, email

Today, I received the following email after an online purchase:

> この度はご注文いただき誠にありがとうございます。
>
> 頂きましたご注文の発送方法について、EMS(国際スピード郵便)による配送となりますので、 送料が1,500円かかります。
>
> よろしければ、クレジット決済金額の変更をし、商品を発送いたします。 お手数をおかけいたしますが、ご返信をお願いいたします。

I am having a great deal of trouble finding common phrases to respond to in e-commerce related conversations over email.

What is the proper way to give the sender permission to proceed?

Every phrase that I would like to use in English seems to have a dual meaning which does not work in Japanese (e.g. please go ahead), or produces very few google results for the phrase which suggests to me that no-one speaks in that manner.

I spent several hours trying to find a way of saying, "Is it possible to use registered shipping instead? If not, please proceed."

My best attempt is something along the lines of

「書留郵便ができるでしょうか？如何とも決済金額の変更して, 追加送料を払ってください。」

but I really have no idea how accurate my vocabulary is. Considering some of these words yield little to no search results when I google them, I suspect this is wrong.

Where can I even find examples of conversations of this nature to learn what to say?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use registered shipping instead? If not, please proceed.
>   EMS(国際スピード郵便)ではなく、[国際書留](http://www.post.japanpost.jp/int/service/option/registered_merit.html)で送っていただくことはできませんか。もし無理なようでしたら、そのまま(1,500円のEMSで)手続きを進めてくださって結構です。

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Speedy EMS (?) does appear have a registered service:

```
https://www.post.japanpost.jp/whats_new/2011/0307_01.html
```

So you could just ask to be told how much it would cost for registered mail. (You never know the cost provided may already be registered)

> 本注文ですが、国際スピード郵便(EMS)と国際書留サービスで郵送していただきたいですが、いかがでしょうか？ 
>   もし可能でしたら、その送料を教えてください。
>
> どうぞよろしくお願い致します

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am particularly interested in how I would ask them to just proceed with the 1500円 shipping option they offered me.

Comment: Actually EMS is registered to start with. Almost all mail (including standard parcels) domestic and international are provided with registration. The three types of international mail provided by Japan Post (Airmail - EMS, Air and Sea - SAL, Land and Sea - 一般) all have registration papers in order to declare and send them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to say proceed.

> 表題の件ですが、承知いたしました。問題ありません。
>
> どうぞよろしくお願い致します